# How to get data from select forms using CBV or FBV

Tags: python, django, forms, get

I'm having an issue displaying data from a Model that is retrieved from a select form. I prefer to use a CBV, but it doesn't matter at this point as long as it solves the issue. I've tried both ways and encounter a different problem for each way. I'll start with my CBV attempt.

views.py

```py
class VehicleCompareView(FormView):
    template_name = "main/vehicle_compare.html"
    form_class = forms.CompareForm

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = forms.CompareForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data
        else:
            data = None
        return self.render_to_response(data)
```

forms.py

```py
class CompareForm(forms.Form):
    objectlist = forms.queryset =     models.Vehicle.objects.all().order_by('make')
```

html

```py
<div class="some class">

    <form name="vform" method="get">
        <select class="form-control" name="v-selection">
            <option value="" selected disabled>Select Vehicle 1</option>
            {% for q in form.objectlist %}
                {% for b in q.package_set.all %}
            <option value="{{q}}" name="v-option">
                {{ q.v_make }} {{ q.v_model }} {{ b.name }}
            </option>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <input value="submit" type="submit">
    </form>

    <div>
        <p>{{data.make}}</p>
    </div>
```

With this I am able to have a dropdown box that allows a selection in the right format, but nothing gets returned after submitting the selection.

The next way I tried was with a FBV. I made these changes:

views.py

```py
def compare_view(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = forms.CompareForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data.get('v-selection')
            return render_to_response('main/vehicle_compare.html', {'data':data}, {'form':form})
    return render_to_response('main/vehicle_compare.html', {'form':form})
```

And I oddly had to change the forms query to the code below. The one that correctly loops the model options causes the view to render the literal html from the vehicle_compare.html file.
forms.py

```py
objectlist = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=models.Vehicle.objects.all())
```

The issue with this is that the objects in the select form no longer appear. What I want to happen is to have the ability to have two forms that allow a user to select an option from each form. Once submitted, the result values should appear on the page. My question is can this be done using CBV how I originally was attempting? If so, how should I go about making the data show on the page, because everything I've tried so far has not worked.

UPDATE: Changing the CBV forms.py to define objectlist using the ModelChoiceField and adding a get function to views.py I can get database objects to display (ex: {{objectlist.make}}, but the form dropdown then disappears. The html now looks like:

```html
<form name="v1form" method="get">
     {{form}}
     <input value="submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

which I do not prefer, but if it worked, I could work on formatting the way I'd like it to look later. But there is no longer a dropdown box. Only a submit button.

Again, just to clarify exactly what I'm trying to do, the end result is two dropdown boxes that contain options from the database to choose from. I would like them to appear as Make Model Package, package being a foreign key to the Vehicle Model that contains make and model. Once the user makes their selections the information from each form should appear.

Comment: I don't understand what `objectlist = forms.queryset =     models.Vehicle.objects.all().order_by('make')` is meant to be doing but your form appears to have 1 field called `objectlist` and this isn't in the html template so the form is never valid

Comment: Defining objectlist the way it is allowed me to loop the model objects in the nested for loop the way they are. When I make a selection and submit it, I can see in the url that the selection was recognized, but I cannot figure out how to display the results. It's called in the html in the first for loop {% for q in form.objectlist %}

Comment: But the form is never valid because you're not return anything in objectlist so form.is_valid() is never True.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I guess I'm just not understanding exactly how the information is passed between the forms and views. I added the form.is_valid() while playing around with the code. Even removing it like it originally was, I'm still not able to get the information displayed. I can see in the url that there is a database related value returned for v-selection. From there I'm just not getting how to display the related objects in the database.

Comment: You should be overriding one of these methods when using CBV's (get_form_data isn't one of them, so it will never be called). 

https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.2/django.views.generic.edit/FormView/

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. This cleared up some things I wasn't sure about, and I've made some corrections, but things still aren't working as I'd like.